# Вызывает ли JVM конвертор, когда мы получаем поля из БД напрямую для DTO

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa, hql

Есть запрос в Dao слое такого плана:

```
return entityManager.createQuery("select new models.dto.chat.NewDto(" +
                "id, title, image) from SomeClass", NewDto.class)
```

Обращается ли в конвертор java, для того что бы собрать сущность с указанными полями, а потом конвертировать и вернуть в контроллер Dto? Или явно по указанным полям создаётся сущность Dto и участие конвертора здесь нет?
Спасибо всем кто пишет по делу! =)

Comment: `Теперь, Федя, скажи Васе все, что ты ему сказал, на гражданском языке.`:)

Comment: @Sergey ээээм))) как бы перевести на "человеческий")) для работы с фронтом используют DTO(вроде распространённая практика), создаются дто-сущности, поля которых могут как совпадать с полями модели(pojo) так и отличаться. Для конвертации одной сущности в другую пользуют конвертер(чтоб получать и отдавать на фронт дто), интересно, при таком запросе, участвует ли конвертр? потому что результат запроса сущность типа DTO. Как то так))) понятнее?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут конвертор никак не используется.

В данном куске кода объект типа `NewDto` создается явно с помощью конструктора из полей сущности `SomeClass`. Реализация JPA ищет в `NewDto` конструктор с параметрами соответствующих типов и вызывает его, чтоб создать объекты.